# Alternative for tartar sauce?

Tags: substitutions, sauce

Is there a substitute for tartar sauce? It is difficult to find in India. I need an alternative that can be obtained in Indian markets.

Answer (score 6):

Tartare sauce is mayonnaise with capers, pickles and lemon juice. Recipe varies to consumer taste.

It's easy to make at home.

Comment: You forgot the minced spring onions...  (or maybe that's a local variety?)  **+1 anyway!  ;-)**

Comment: I find plain yogurt a more than adequate replacement for mayonnaise.